# How to tell Travis to skip pulling all git submodules in?

Tags: git-submodules, travis-ci

In my project I have a few git submodules, however those aren't actual build dependencies and do take some extra time to get pulled in, literarily doubling or tripling the build time.

Is there any way of telling Travis to skip this useless step?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In case if somebody still looks for this, in `.travis.yml`:

```
git:
  submodules: false
```

Comment: Docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Git-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

At the moment not, please file an issue with [travis-build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/issues/new).

Comment: I believe this is the followup on this: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/pull/46